# C# IOrderedQueryable Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I received this error at the "ThenBy" section

```
Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable
```

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Common.Constant;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Common
{
    public static class LinqHelper
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDefault<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool isInitialQueryable)
        {
            var ordered = source as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>;

            if (ordered == null || isInitialQueryable)
            {
                return source.OrderBy(keySelector); // <<-- no issue for this line. the system will get into here for the first column
            }
            else
            {
                return ordered.ThenBy(keySelector); // <<-- this line will prompt above error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, the system should be able to generate the codes for sorting.. The codes have no issue to run the first "if statement".. but will fail on "else statement"

Comment: `ordered` is not null, but not an ordered queryable, so you can't call `ThenBy()` on it.

Comment: but if it is not an orderedqueryable, it will execute source.OrderBy instead of ordered.ThenBy

Comment: `ordered` is not null, so it'll go into the `else` block.

Comment: What is OrderByDescendingSimple? What is the type of `result`? A [mcve] would really help... (I'd also strongly advise you to change indentation style - at the moment each case statement looks like three separate statements before the break due to the lack of indentation...)

Comment: It is because LINQ Provider's `IQueryable` implementations aways supports `IOrderedQueryable` to simplify things. You have to check that `source.Expression` expression is not MethodCall `OrderBy`,  `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`

Comment: Based on the response from Svyatoslav Danyliv, I have changed the parameter from "IQueryable source" to "IOrderedQueryable source"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response from Svyatoslav Danyliv, I have changed the parameter from "this IQueryable source" to this "IOrderedQueryable source"

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool isInitialQueryable, bool isDescending)
        {
            if (isInitialQueryable)
            {
                if (isDescending)
                {
                    return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
                }
                else
                {
                    return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (isDescending)
                {
                    return source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
                }
                else
                {
                    return source.ThenBy(keySelector);
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is example of how I use the function

```
private IOrderedQueryable<Mt_User> PopulateSortingCondition(SortingInfo[] criteria, IQueryable<Mt_User> source)
        {
            var initialQuery = source as IOrderedQueryable<Mt_User>;
            IOrderedQueryable<Mt_User> result = null;
            var isResetCondition = true;
            var isUnhandledField = false;

            if (criteria != null && criteria.Any())
            {
                foreach (var field in criteria)
                {
                    isUnhandledField = false;

                    switch (field.Selector)
                    {
                        case "COMPANYDESCR":
                            result = initialQuery.OrderBy(Mt_User => (Mt_User.Account.CODE + " - " + Mt_User.Account.COMPANYNAME + " - " + Mt_User.Account.DESCR), isResetCondition, field.Desc);
                            break;
                        case "ACCESSRIGHT":
                            result = initialQuery.OrderBy(Mt_User => (Mt_User.Role.CODE), isResetCondition, field.Desc);
                            break;
                        case "USERNAME":
                            result = initialQuery.OrderBy(Mt_User => (Mt_User.Contact.NAME), isResetCondition, field.Desc);
                            break;
                        default:
                            isUnhandledField = true;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!isUnhandledField)
                    {
                        initialQuery = result;
                        isResetCondition = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (result == null)
            {
                result = initialQuery
               .OrderBy(Mt_User => Mt_User.Contact.NAME)
                .ThenBy(Mt_User => Mt_User.Role.CODE)
                .ThenBy(Mt_User => Mt_User.Account.CODE + " - " + Mt_User.Account.COMPANYNAME + " - " + Mt_User.Account.DESCR);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the check is always returning true, that the queryable is always ordered. Not 100% sure why that's happening. Maybe the query provider that is producing it as an ordered queryable from the start before any other work is done to it.

This method checks if the queryable is ordered in a way that seems to work when I test it:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDefault<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool isInitialQueryable)
{
  if (source.Expression.Type != typeof(IOrderedQueryable<TSource>) || isInitialQueryable)
  {
    return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
  }
  else
  {
    return (source as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>).ThenBy(keySelector);
  }
}
```

I also tried a version with this in the if statement instead, but it would always end up in the OrderBy section:

```
if (!typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(source.Expression.Type) || isInitialQueryable)
```